# Ecmascript 6 Map filter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to filter data in a Map by value?

I have implemented the `forEach` and then added the key-values to another Map (as it is not recommended to delete the map while iterating)

`theMap.forEach((value, key) => { if (value !== 'something') { otherMap.set(key, value)}})`

Is there any more efficient way to filter the Map by value? I tried using `lodash` filter function but couldn't implement it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably easiest would be to create a temporary array while iterating, like

```
Array.from(theMap).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (someFilterLogic) theMap.delete(key);
});
```

or create a new `Map` instead, e.g.

```
theMap = new Map(Array.from(theMap).filter(([key, value]) => someFilterLogic));
```

Generally worrying about "efficient" with JS code is best left to a profiler. What counts as efficient varies massively between browsers and versions. Unless you've profiled and explicitly know something is a bottleneck, or have written your code with a truly incorrect algorithmic runtime, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like

```
var m = new Map()
m.set("a", {x: 1})
m.set("b", {x: 2})
m.set("c", {x: 3})
var f = new Map([...m].filter(v => v[1].x >= 3))
```

where of course you can change the filter depending of your map values type